# awk, sed, shell: How to use data from one file to another

Tags: bash, shell, awk, cat

I have two files with the following format:

File1.txt

```
1
apple 1.056
ref 15
```

File2.txt

```
2
apple unknown
ref unknown1
```

How can I have the value for apple (1.056) from File1.txt be used in place of the what's written for File2.txt? I would like File2.txt to be updated to read:

```
2
apple 1.056
ref 15
```

I'm thinking a grep command may work but I'm unsure how to go about it. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Please explain the whole problem, cause now it is possible to get the result you want by just copying Fil1.txt to File2.txt and replace the first line.

Comment: Does file2 really have an unknown..unknownn column or is this just part of your example?

Comment: File1.txt and File2.txt can be structured very differently. apple from File1.txt may be on a different line than File2.txt

Comment: Btw: this works only because both files already sorted: `join --header file2 file1 -o 1.1,2.2`

Answer (score 3):

> How can I have the value for apple (1.056) from File1.txt be used in
>   place of the what's written for File2.txt? I would like File2.txt to
>   be updated to read:

Straight forward `awk` which is repeated several times in fora, please search before posting.

**Input**

```
$ cat f1
1
apple 1.056
ref 15

$ cat f2
2
apple unknown
ref unknown1
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next}($1 in a){$2=a[$1]}1' f1 f2
2
apple 1.056
ref 15
```

Comment: These problems will never fade away :) but still a good & working answer ++

Comment: Thanks Akshay Hegde.... The problem with this method is that it switches out all the common variables. What if I only want to change apple? How can I make this specific to key variables?

Comment: @user7649922 When you do not want to change ref, modify the requirements (example output).